# How to access files on a Linux computer from a Windows PC in a graphically way

Tags: linux, windows-10, ssh, windows-explorer

I can ssh connect to my linux computer.
I would like to access files from my linux computer but in a more comfortable graphical way, so that for example I can see them in a "file explorer" type of thing and can copy and paste it in my windows computer

Is there a simple way to do that?

Comment: Look into [WinSCP](https://winscp.net/eng/index.php)

Comment: Set your Linux box up with SAMBA and do file sharing with your Windows box.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [SSHFS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SSHFS). This allows you to mount your server filesystem using `SSH` credentials (and relevant access granted to `SSH` user, of course) as a directory on your Windows machine.

On `Windows 10`, you can use [SSHFS for Windows](https://github.com/billziss-gh/sshfs-win) and [WinFSP](https://github.com/billziss-gh/winfsp/releases/tag/v1.9) (directions given in SSHFS GitHub page). These are simple installations, thereafter you'll be able to mount your remote directory on your machine via SSH, and browse the file system using Windows File Explorer, just as if it was on your own system. Nothing is required to be installed on your server except, of course, the `SSH` server.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Mobaxterm](https://mobaxterm.mobatek.net/) Home Edition.

When you open a new ssh session  you have next to the terminal a ssh browser and you can drag and drop files from/to it.